# Route in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I am a newbie to Laravel. I am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOx93.png). Please advise?

```php
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/Dashboard',function(){
  return view('layouts.master');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `;` at the end of line 22.

```
Route::get('/Dashboard',function(){
  return view('layouts.master');
}) // <---- HERE
```

Like this:

```
Route::get('/Dashboard',function(){
  return view('layouts.master');
});
```